# Pass Dynamic Parameter to SQL

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

I'm trying to create a dynamic parameter in Excel.

I've tried used this [link](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2014/11/26/building-a-parameter-table-for-power-query/) and this [one](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2016/04/28/pass-parameters-to-sql-queries/), but I get the following error:

> An error occurred in the ‘’ query. Expression.Error: We couldn't find
>   an Excel table named 'Parameters'.

My Parameters sheet look as following and the table is also called Parameters:

[image: Parameters]

My Parmeters code is as following:

```
(ParameterName as text) =>
let
ParamSource = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Parameters"]}[Content],
ParamRow = Table.SelectRows(ParamSource, each ([Parameter] = ParameterName)),
Value=
if Table.IsEmpty(ParamRow)=true
then null
else Record.Field(ParamRow{0},"Value")
in
Value
```

My SQL Query is as following:

```
let
//Pull in a values from the parameter table
SQL_Instance = fnGetParameter("SQL Instance"),
dbName = fnGetParameter("Database Name"),
dbTable = fnGetParameter("Database Table"),
sFilterField = fnGetParameter("Filter Field"),
sFieldValue = Text.From(fnGetParameter("Field Value")),

//Create the query
dbQuery = "Select * FROM " & dbTable & " WHERE " & sFilterField & "='" & sFieldValue & "'",

//Get the data
Source = Sql.Database(SQL_Instance,dbName,[Query=dbQuery])
in
Source
```

How do I get this to work, without receiving the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific error you're seeing indicates that your parameter table in Excel is not named 'Parameters'. Tables in Excel are represented as special named ranges. You can edit the name of a table by:

1. Selecting any cell in the table
2. Navigating to the 'Table Design' ribbon menu
3. Editing the table name at the far left of the ribbon.

Note the other answers about the general bad idea of building SQL statements by string concatenation - this is a real concern.

[image: showing the table design ribbon menu]

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't find that!

Answer (score 3):

You can't parametrise an object in SQL; you have to inject its value **safely**. Most likely you'll want to create an SP to do this, but the SQL you want will be along the lines of this:

```
DECLARE @DBTable sysname,
        @FilterField sysname,
        @FilterValue varchar(50); --choose an appropriate data type here

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@DBTAble) + N' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@FilterField) + N' = @FilterValue;';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@FilterValue varchar(50)', @FilterValue; --again, choose an appropriate data type for @FilterValue
```

Note the use of `QUOTENAME` to **safely** inject the value of the dynamic objects, along with passing `@FilterValue` as a parameter, not injecting it to the dynamic statement.